# Install OSSEC on Windows Server without GUI

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, gui

The installation and configuration of the OSSEC windows agent requires a GUI. However I am running an environment which has cmd and powershell only. Is there a way to install and configure from the command line, similar to the linux installations?

Comment: If 'OSSEC' does not provide CLI install, then no. PowerShell cannot change that. If it is s generic MSI file, then that is your option. If it is not, then, GUI you must use. You can try to automate that.

Comment: a lot of setup.exe or any other exe can also be started via GUI in Servercore. put it somewhere on the server, connect to the server via remote-desktop of some sort (NOT via Remote PSSession) and run `ii C:\path\setup.exe` and see what happens